# Premature end of script headers on one server but not another

Tags: apache, unix

I have two servers.  They are both running the same code and are connected to the same database.  But when I make a certain ajax call, one server works fine, and the other throws an Internal Server Error. Inside the Apache log of the internal service error server, it says 'Premature end of script headers'. This makes me think that there is some Apache error on one machine, but the Apache folder looks identical on both machines.

What sort of differences between servers would cause one to throw this error?

Comment: `Premature end of script headers` simply means that a CGI script started outputting some info before outputting the headers, which is possible due to an error in the script.

Comment: But then why does an identical script cause an error on one server but not another?

Comment: Because, apparently, the environments are not identical? Setup, filesystem, httpd config differences?

Comment: I have this exact issue. Was there ever a resolution found?

Comment: @DerrellDurrett It was a really stupid bug on my part.  I deleted a folder by accident.  The servers weren't actually identical.

Answer (score 0):

The error tells that you that no headers were output where they should be output. Typically it happens with a cgi script that fails for some reason and hence does not output anything, or outputs stuff before outputting the headers.

To debug it: Look in the apache error log. It will most likely tell you what went wrong.

To find the error_log: Look for the ErrorLog directive in the apache configuration file.

Answer (score 0):

Swa66 etc have provided good answers but I thought that I would add a few more things to look into after you you reviewed the apache error logs which should give you the text that was returned where Apache was expecting a valid http header.

You mentioned that the servers are responding to Ajax queries and so it is possible that you are having some kind of CORS issues or issues relating to how Apache is configured to allow HTTP headers to be passed through to the CGI process.
It is not uncommon to include JWT or other auth headers as part of an ajax service and you may find that you need to add either a .htaccess file permitting these to flow through

Check your working server to see if the headers module is enabled ( - something like this in you httpd.conf - LoadModule headers_module libexec/apache2/mod_headers.so )

Also look for the .htaccess or domain specific configuration of the header related options. If need be, have a dig around relating to Apache CORS configuration and header related issues.

You may need some kinds of configuration similar to the following.

**.htaccess**

```
SetEnvIf Authorization .+ HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$0
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```

It is a little difficult to be certain of your issue without more specific diagnostics. Perhaps you could provide debugger details from your browser describing the Ajax/XHR requests including the headers etc and the relevant error log entries from apache. Assuming that you are using Perl/CGI perhaps snippets describing the CGI configuration from the config and any .htaccess files on the working and errant server.

You may also want to do a quick check of the permissions of the executables and try to run them from the command line.

It could be a very basic configuration option such as described at [apache centos fails to serve images - premature end of script headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33286696/apache-centos-fails-to-serve-images-premature-end-of-script-headers?rq=1) .. we really need a little more diagnostic detail to focus on possible causes.

Comment: In my case, there was no additional text identifying the relevant header.

As it turned out, my problem was due to some issue with the configuration, but it was impossible to identify what was the relevant difference once it was working (which was well after I offered the bounty)-- the changes that were made to get it working couldn't be reliably backed out to duplicate the error, and the error_log contents were largely meaningless.