# apache centos fails to serve images - premature end of script headers

Tags: apache

I can't figure out why my apache centos server fails to serve images.  I see "premature end of script headers" message in the error_log file.  Text is served fine as the first line of my perl script is:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl -w
```

and the first line I send is

```
print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
```

The permissions on the files and folder is 755.  I've tried .jpg and .gif files but neither works.

I've added

```
AddType image/gif .gif .GIF
AddType image/jpeg .jpeg .jpg .jpe .JPG
```

To the /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf file.
I've uncommented "#EnableSendfile off" in the same file and restarted the server and flushed the browser cache.  Nothing worked.

Any other ideas?

Comment: Look for `SetHandler` directives, it sounds like httpd treats everything in your folder as a cgi script, including the images.

Comment: I searched for SetHandler in httpd.conf and found two instances, both were commented out.  I searched for ScriptAlias and found ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/var/www/cgi-bin/"

#
# "/var/www/cgi-bin" should be changed to whatever your ScriptAliased
# CGI directory exists, if you have that configured.
#
<Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Default Apache comes with the following in your httpd.conf file:

```
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/var/www/cgi-bin/"
```

As [the manual says](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/cgi.html):

> The ScriptAlias directive tells Apache that a particular directory is set aside for CGI programs. Apache will assume that every file in this directory is a CGI program, and will attempt to execute it, when that particular resource is requested by a client.

This means that Apache is attempting to run your image files a cgi scripts causing the error you see.

There are two options.

1. The preferred option would be to serve none-cgi content like images from outside the cgi-bin folder. For example use the default web root '/var/www/html/' (Some distros may change this).
2. Tell Apache not to handle all files as cgi.

Replace this:

```
 ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/var/www/cgi-bin/"
```

With this:

```
Alias /cgi-bin/ "/var/www/cgi-bin/"
<Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin/">
   Options +ExecCGI
</Directory>
AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl
```

Comment: Ah! Thank you! I put the image in /var/www/html and that worked!